# Azure AD Authentication redirects to home page

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-authentication

I'm building an Azure AD authentication which works fine, the only issue is that if a user clicks on a link that looks like host.com/xxx/bbb if they're not authenticated then they get redirected to root.

I need them to still be redirected to the original URL they entered in the browser. Can can this be achieved? Below is a snippet of the code I use in app startup:

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = XXX,
                Authority = string.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}", YYY,

                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = async n => { await Task.Run(() => SetRedirectUrl(n)); }
                }
            });
    }

private static void SetRedirectUrl(RedirectToIdentityProviderNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
    {
        notification.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = notification.Request.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
    }
```

None of the properties of OwinRequest contain a full path I'm looking for. I've also tried looking at

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url
```

but this also does not have the full address.

Answer (score 0):

> I need them to still be redirected to the original URL they entered in
>   the browser

You need to set the `SignIn()` method in AccountController.cs. You could use “Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();” to get the entered url:

```html
public void SignIn()
        {

            // var host = Request.UserHostName.ToString();
            var ori = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
            var index = ori.LastIndexOf('/');
            var action = ori.Substring(index);
            // Send an OpenID Connect sign-in request.
            if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = action },
                    OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            }
        }
```